# How to detect if user operating system is windows 8 htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I just wonder, if there is a way to detect if a user browser is using windows 8 operating system using htaccess only,

just so I could redirect the user to the windows store to download an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check against the user-agent. Microsoft has [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) what Windows 8 user-agent strings look like:

> Be aware that "Windows NT 6.2" indicates the browser is on a computer running Windows 8

While you can easily match against the user-agent using mod_rewrite, the question is what do you plan on doing? If it just redirecting a request for `/start-here.html` to the windows store (e.g. `http://windows-store/app`) then it'll look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Windows\ NT\ 6\.2
RewriteRule ^start-here\.html$ http://windows-store/app [L,R]
```

Comment: Windows NT 6.3 is Windows 8.1